# Does database connection return to pool if a thread holding it dies?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and Mysql. I am using multi-threading and giving connections to different threads by using `PooledDB` . I give db connections to different threads by
`pool.dedicated_connection()`.Now if a thread takes a connection from pool and dies due to some reason with closing it(ie. without returning it to the pool).What happens to this connection.
If it lives forever how to return it to the pool??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not.  You have to tell the server on the other side that the connection is closed, because it can't tell the difference between "going away" and "I haven't sent my next query yet" without an explicit signal from you.

The connection can time out, of course, but it won't be closed or cleaned up without instructions from you.